# Neo4j LOAD CSV extremely slow when merging relations from a label of 3mil nodes to a lable of 20 nodes

Tags: csv, neo4j, load, cypher

neo4j 2.2.0 in a 3-machine cluster, with ~3 million "User" nodes and ~10 "Brand" nodes

When loading the ~20k rows of ":LIKES" relationship by:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 30000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file://path/to/my/file.csv" AS csvLine
MATCH (user:User {id: toInt(csvLine.userId)})
MATCH (brand:Brand {id: csvLine.brandId})
MERGE (user)-[:LIKES]->(brand)
```

It never succeeded. Sometimes it took about 6 minutes then caused master-slave swap and failed with error "Transaction has been terminated." Other times it took more than 10 minutes and caused http transaction reset. Unusual garbage collection pattern had been observed when loading. Profile showed the two "MATCH"s took very few time. So it should be the MERGE that caused the slowness and the eventual failure. Unfortunately nothing further from the profile to show what was done inside the MERGE to cause the slowness.

The node counts and relationship counts both seemed reasonable. Loading other relations that link ~3 mil nodes to another ~2 mil nodes only took a couple of minutes. So one suspicion is, the problem is due to linking too many users to too few brands at the same time? Neo4j couldnot parallel in this case? Why so many GCs were triggered?

I hoped "profile" could tell more details, such as how much time has been spent on each section, and a further breakdown of how the time has been spent on, for example, Cypher compiler, or other kernel activities? Is there a way to read internal *operation* log?

Any suggestion or ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have indexes created for `:User(id)` and `:Brand(id)`?

Comment: Can you share your EXPLAIN output? (leave off periodic commit for it to work).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have an index or constraint for `:User(id)` and `:Brand(id)`.

You can also try to replace MERGE with CREATE and assert the uniqueness before

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file://path/to/my/file.csv" AS csvLine
WITH distinct toInt(csvLine.userId) as userId, csvLine.brandId as brandId
MATCH (user:User {id: userId})
MATCH (brand:Brand {id: brandId})
MERGE (user)-[:LIKES]->(brand)
```

Perhaps your brand is a dense ndoe, can you try to reverse the direction of the arrow? `MERGE (brand)<-[:LIKES]-(user)`

Comment: Reverse the MERGE didn't help.

Comment: Michael, I could not post images for the profile or vm visualizer (don't have enough reputation yet :-( ) ... anyway the "profile load csv" took 589682msec to finishm with the MERGE, on a 100k rows file. If replacing the MERGE with a return, it took only 12463 msec. The 100k size worked fine with other relations (even 500k was fast), but not this one. I am chunking up the csv files into multiple smaller files and trying again. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Michael and cybersam. Found the reason to be the MERGE on the dense nodes. Internally neo4j 2.2.0 uses linked lists (2-way) for all nodes having the same relationship, a new MERGE means 2 linked list scan which are not indexed, so scanning on the dense node's list will take longer and longer as more relations added.

Our workaround is to use CREATE when dumping the big chunk of relations in. Then update with MERGE on a much smaller dataset periodically.

However the problem is still there and it is not always possible to CREATE. neo said they will improve it.

Comment: "neo said they will improve it" : two years on and its still slow